# Prevent parent window's mouse or keyboard events until child window is closed

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a scenario where both the parent and child windows are opened. I need to prevent the user's mouse or keyboard actions on parent window until child window is closed by the user.

Parent window(old browser Tab) is opened by default. On button click the child window(new browser tab) will open.

I am opening the child window as below:

```
 const newwindow = window.open("", "", "width=80%,height=80%");
 newwindow.document.write("Hello");
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what you are using? Frameworks? Post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get inspired on how Angular's cdk-overlay works with modal window.

It's basically a wrapper that takes the whole windows with a huge z-index css property.
It then displays window as its second child You can then handle any interaction in the window and on the outside for the first child
"overlay backdrop".

Your 100%/100% wrapper area can be completely invisible and have a   `pointer-events: none;` and it's sibling can be the floating window.

Handling it completely in TypeScript is possible, however angular doesn't care if you create complex templates or create your own solution with `document.createElement*` and `@HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) public onClick(target) { ...`

Comment: pointer-events: none; Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `stopPropatation`

```
$("#clickable a").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I want the solution in Typescript.

Comment: Give us more info and post some code of what you are trying to do please. We're not going to code for you, but help you figuring out the solution.